# How to have a child image be larger then a parent div and be positioned anywhere

Tags: css, image, html

I have a parent container div with `display: inline-block`. This allows me to adjust the image height using % values. I can't adjust the width beyond 100% though which I need.

How in css/html can I setup a `parent div` and `child image` so that I can use % values to scale the image larger then the parent and position the image top and left with % values?

Comment: Why would the image need to be larger than it's parent?

Comment: @Jon Rose : Please put up your code to play with

Comment: a child should generally never be larger than a parent, unless you're using absolute positioning on the child.

Comment: You could use "position:absolute" "top:"/"bottom:" and "width:"/"height:" attributes. I assume, though, that you want the image to be bound to the div? Otherwise, consider using javascript to set the dimensions.

Comment: While making a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W2z7L/) I realized the problem was in my project. I am using Zurb Foundation which has a default max-image: 100% setting. I am doing this to center an image scaled to fill it's parents size.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
div {
    width:  50%; 
}
img {
    width: 150%;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2M9xZ/)